# Numpy argsort strange indices

Tags: python, numpy

The first output is correct. But somehow `argsort` gives wrong output for the second array:

```
>>> np.argsort(np.array([ 0.62678927,  0.36816272,  0.31044763,  0.44873312,  0.3101446 ]))
array([4, 2, 1, 3, 0])

>>> np.argsort(np.array([ 0.36816272,  0.62678927,  0.13509969,  0.54590815,  0.13493432]))
array([4, 2, 0, 3, 1])
```

After spending 2 hours on it, I'm convinced that this problem is either too trivial or too technical.
I'm using Anaconda virtual environments and have tested it with numpy 1.11.3 and 1.10.4

Comment: What is the issue exactly? The output is correct as 0.13493432 < 0.13509969 < 0.36816272 < 0.54590815 < 0.62678927.

Comment: but the result seems correct, what did you expect?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. But I was expecting the second command to return `[2, 4, 1, 3, 0]`. As 0.6 is the largest it should have a number `4` associated with it. What am I missing?

Comment: But that would be the indices after sorting the array but `argsort` returns the "_indices that would sort the array_" (Source: [argsort documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html#numpy-argsort))

Comment: @MSeifert. Got it. I'm dumb. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Note also that your expected result is exactly the inverse of the output of `np.argsort` as a permutation; that is, you could get your expected result through `s = np.argsort(a)`, `s_inv = np.empty(5)`, `s_inv[s] = np.arange(5)`. It is thus rather unfortunate that in your first case, `s[s]` happens to be `np.arange(5)`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're under the impression that `np.argsort(x)` returns an array such that `np.argsort(x)[i]` is where `x[i]` goes in sorted order. That's not how it works.

`np.argsort(x)` returns an array such that `x[np.argsort(x)[i]]` goes in position `i` in sorted order. This produces the effect that

```
x[np.argsort(x)]
```

is equivalent to

```
np.sort(x)
```

This happens to produce the same result as the behavior you expected for the first array, but not for the second.